# C: Getting Bad access upon trying to read int from .dat file

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to read a file of integers and print them as I read them.  However I am getting bad access on the first iteration through the loop.  Any ideas why?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    FILE *fr = fopen("testdata1.dat","r");
        int output;
        do {
            fscanf(fr, "%d", &output);

            printf("%d", output);
        }
        while(output != EOF); // check to make sure user has input
}
```

The first few lines of .dat are

```
1000 0 100 2 90 2 80 3 70 2 60 2 10 -99
1001 8 80 2 80 2 50 3 70 2 40 2 10 -99
```

Comment: Have you ensured that `fr` is not `NULL` after the `fopen()`? Also, your integer `output` isn't what gets compared to `EOF`...

Comment: Can you post a small complete program that reproduces the problem?

Comment: could you post the first few lines of  "test.dat" ?

Comment: Actually I just noticed the address for the File pointer IS 0x0000000.. sorry i misunderstood xcodes dev tools

Comment: also you're opening two files one at FILE *fr = fopen() and fr = fopen() again. this is causing the fault. I posted a fix below.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
FILE *fr = (FILE*) fopen("test.dat","r");

// ERROR HERE: fr=fopen("test.dat","r");
int output;
if(!feof(fr)){
 do {
    fscanf(fr, "%d", &output);

    printf("%d", output);
  }
   while(!feof(fr)); // check to make sure user has input
 fclose(fr);
 return 0;
}
```

Retry with this code.

I can't think of any problems other than incorrect permissions, unfindable file..

Comment: can we see your entire code? There is something wrong with your code BEFORE the fr = fopen()

Comment: feof() is (*almost)* always wrong. In your case one garbage value will be witten to the output. (probably the last valid value will be duplicated)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using Xcode to develop my program..dragging the file to the project didn't place it in the same folder as the executable

Answer (score 0):

try this：

```
enter code here

#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
int output;
FILE *fr = fopen("test.dat","rb");

if(ferror(fr)!=0){
    fprintf(stderr,"Error in reading file.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
while(feof(fr) == 0){
    fread(&output,sizeof(int),1,fr);
    printf("%d\n",output);
}

fclose(fr);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.