# while with EOF in C

Tags: c, file, eof

I'm trying to read the data from a txt file with the following code but it's print only the first line from file.

```
int main() {
    int chave;
    char ordem[5];
    struct tTree *arvore = (struct tTree*)malloc(sizeof(struct tTree));
    arvore->raiz = NULL;
    scanf("%s", ordem); 
    printf("%s\n", ordem);
    setbuf(stdin, NULL);  
    do {
        scanf("%d", &chave);
        insere(criaItem(chave), arvore);
        setbuf(stdin, NULL); 
    } while(chave != EOF);

    if(strcmp(ordem, "PRE") == 0) {
        pre(arvore->raiz);
    }
    else if(strcmp(ordem, "POS") == 0){
        pos(arvore->raiz);
    }
    else if(strcmp(ordem, "IN") == 0){
        in(arvore->raiz);
    }
    printf("%d\n", altura(arvore->raiz)-1);
    system("pause");   
}
```

Comment: You must not use `chave` *before* you've tested it!!

Comment: Where do you open the file you're reading from?

Comment: This question is strikingly similar to another that was asked yesterday. Same loop, and using an int to check for EOF.

This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018224/c-getting-bad-access-upon-trying-to-read-int-from-dat-file

Are these people reading some bad book or reference?

Comment: i have made a .bat file with the following code: arvore.exe<in1.txt>out.txt, and the in1.txt file has:PRE
5
3
8
2
4
7
9
but the program prints only the first line "PRE".

Answer (score 2):

```
while (scanf("%d", &chave) == 1)
{
    insere(criaItem(chave), arvore);
    printf("Read: %d\n", chave);  // Debugging
    // setbuf(stdin, NULL);  // Pointless once there's been an I/O operation on stdin
}
```

This tests for EOF and other errors correctly, with the test up front.  Almost always, it is best to do the read operation and test that it succeeded at the start of the loop.

There were a large number of problems with what you'd written, not least of which was that typing `-1` as an input value would have terminated your loop.

Comment: It's not just "best", its usually outright undefined behaviour to read a variable that was used in a failed input operation.

Comment: I have made a .bat file with the following code: arvore.exe<in1.txt>out.txt, and the in1.txt file has:PRE 5 3 8 2 4 7 9 but the program prints only the first line "PRE".

Comment: For debugging, you should add a `printf("Read: %d\n", chave);` in the body of the loop.  That'll tell you whether your input was read.  (You should only call `setbuf()` once, before you do any operations on the stream; my bad for not pointing that out before!)  Then you need to review whether the `insere()` and `creaItem()` functions are working, and finally whether `pos()` is working.  Without their code, there's no more help we can provide.

Answer (score 0):

**scanf()** will *return* EOF, but not put it into **chave**.  Shouldn't your code look something more like this?

```
int ret;
do {
    ret = scanf("%d", &chave);
    if ( ret == 1) {
        insere(criaItem(chave), arvore);
        setbuf(stdin, NULL); 
    }
} while( ret != EOF);
```